# Machine level memory theory

Tags: c

I have a question for my homework, and I would love it if someone could give me an answer, but more importantly if they could explain to me in details what is happening at machine level.

Choose any platform you want and describe what happens at machine level in the
execution of the code below when func() is called.

What changes if foo is inlined?

```
int foo( int a, int* b)
{
    return a + *b;
}

extern int x;

void func()
{
    int y = 7;
    int r;
    r = foo( x, &y );
    printf("%d\n", r);
}
```

Comment: You would benefit from generating the assembly for this code, and read it : you'll find all your answers.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subroutine

Comment: FYI: Standard optimizations will change the code much...

Comment: I don't think I ll benefit much, I can't understand assembly !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming no optimization is occurring, the basic difference between a function call and an inline call is that there is no functional scope added.  With a function call, a function scope is pushed on the program stack and is used to accommodate local variables to the function, etc.  Upon return, all that stuff is popped off the stack.

With an inline function, the code is simply pasted into the current routine, nothing is pushed on the stack.  One can see for simple routines, this can be beneficial.  An inline routine is sort of (conceptually) halfway between a function and a macro in C parlance.

Answer (score 3):

Use your compiler. If you have [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), try first

```
 gcc -S -Wall -fverbose-asm -O0 yourcode.c -o yourcode-O0.s
```

then compile again with optimizations, e.g.

```
 gcc -S -Wall -fverbose-asm -O2 yourcode.c -o yourcode-O2.s
```

and look at the produced assembler code:

```
 less yourcode-O0.s
 less yourcode-O2.s
```

You might even look at intermediate GCC representations. Add `-fdump-tree-all` to the compilation flags above (caveat, you'll get hundreds of textual "dump" files).

Comment: Great thanks, but what do I do once I have my assembly code? I can't really understand any of it...

Comment: Learn to understand it : there's plenty of tutorials to learn assembly on the Internet.

Comment: I believe this is a useful answer and you will greatly benefit by doing the extra mile to understand.